# Are there any good webapps that will convert an RSS feed to email?

Tags: webapp-rec, email, rss, feeds

I find that some RSS feeds are more useful if they were sent to me as email messages instead. Are there any good services that will monitor an RSS feed and send the new posts as email messages?

Comment: good question :), why webservices?

Answer (score 8):

[FeedBurner](http://feedburner.com) can do this, create a 'burnt' version of your feed then enable 'Email Subscriptions', then subscribe to the feed. It's a little more complicated than FeedMyInbox but doesn't have a 5 feed limit

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Note: It only sends daily digest.

Answer (score 7):

http://blogtrottr.com/ is doing the same as feedmyinbox.

It allows the user to choose the frequency it sends emails. From realtime to daily: [image]

Comment: Blogtrottr, IMO, is the simplest to use out of all recommendations here so far. All it needs is an RSS feed and an email address.

Comment: Very similar to Blogtrottr but with RSS feeds grouping: [Feedspot](http://feedspot.com).

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have a look at http://ifttt.com/ (If This Then That).

You create "tasks" from ifft "channels" that can be used as both sources and sinks ("triggers" and "actions" in ifft parlance).  The RSS and email channels are enabled by default; others are available by opting in.

The RSS channel used as a trigger can activate when either a new item is added to a feed URL or a new item appears that matches a key word or phrase that you define.  The email channel used as an action can use "addins" from the trigger source in the message (e.g. the entry title, content, etc., in the RSS case).  The default addins for the RSS channel are reasonable for an email action.

Each of your tasks is checked every fifteen minutes.  Note that you being subscribed to a particular feed is not a prerequisite to use the feed URL in a trigger.

If you are interested, and sign-ups are closed, I do have a few invites to give out.

Answer (score 4):

[FeedMyInbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) does this, although you have to pay if you want to subscribe to more than 5 feeds.

Comment: Note: It only sends daily digests.