# Instant notification for RSS feed?

Tags: rss, notifications

I have an RSS feed I'm monitoring for changes. Is there some web service that provides a way to be notified by email *immediately*<sup>**</sup> when a new post is added?

<sub>** When I say immediately, I mean within 1 - 2 minutes.</sub>

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/are-there-any-good-webapps-that-will-convert-an-rss-feed-to-email

Comment: As RSS does not have an push protocol but it's based on pulling I don't think there is a service that does it. To have an notification time of 2 minutes the service needs to download the feed 720 times a day and might get blocked by the website.

Comment: @neo RSS Cloud is an extension to the RSS protocol that enables real-time push notifications

Comment: @systempuntoot: Yes, but as all with all other new protocol both sides needs to support it, the client and the server.

Comment: @neo Wordpress, SixApart, Blogger, Tumblr, Posterous have adopted PubSubHubbub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

George, you need to check if the publisher's feed is pushing its RSS feed with some push protocol; [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pubsubhubbub) for example.

> PubSubHubbub is an open protocol for
>   distributed Publish/subscribe
>   communication on the internet. The
>   protocol extends the Atom and RSS 
>   protocols for data feeds. The main
>   purpose is to provide near-instant
>   notifications of change updates, which
>   would improve on the typical situation
>   where a client periodically polls the
>   feed server at some arbitrary
>   interval.

[Here](http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/) an hub hosted on Google App Engine.
Give it a [try](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe).

You could also register to [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) that handles pushed contents via PubSubHubbub, RSSCloud, XML-RPC or SUP.
Answering some comments, if your feed's publisher does not use this kind of push technology, superfeedr (via polling) guarantee delivery of new entries within 15 minutes of their publication.

Comment: But it has to be implemented on the publisher side, too.

Comment: doesn't it only work if the publisher implements this? Can I take any random feed that I subscribe to and use PubSubHubbub with it?

Comment: @eagle See my edit.