# How do I get a daily email containing every new article from all of my RSS feeds?

Tags: email, webapp-rec, rss, feeds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good webapps that will convert an RSS feed to email?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/are-there-any-good-webapps-that-will-convert-an-rss-feed-to-email)

I'm looking for a service that will let me enter a bunch of RSS feeds then send me a daily email, at a given time, containing all of the new articles up to that time. [Feed My Inbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) is close to what I want, but it seems to send a separate email for each feed, and given the number of feeds I have, I'd be paying $16/mo, which is a bit steep (though not at all a deal-breaker)

Any ideas?

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2911/are-there-any-good-webapps-that-will-convert-an-rss-feed-to-email

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could aggregate all of your feeds using [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com), then create a [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com) feed for your Pipe, then subscribe to the Feedburner feed by email.