# Link an RSS feed to an e-mail account

Tags: email, rss

Can I link an RSS feed to an e-mail account? In other words, so each time there is a new item in the feed I'll get a notification by e-mail?

Comment: Need to specify your webmail host, and don't say "any" because that makes your question too broad

Comment: I meant an (web)app as an interference between a RSS-feed and an email address, not a webmail-function

Comment: Questions seeking application recommendations are off-topic unless they detail what has already been tried and rejected. Describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1003

Comment: See also: [Are there any good webapps that will convert an RSS feed to email?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2911)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embrace the magic of [if-this-then-that](http://ifttt.com).

Recipes such as [this one](https://ifttt.com/recipes/533) allow for consuming an RSS feed and sending an email message for new items. There are dozens (if not hundreds) of recipes for specific RSS feeds.

If you want to build your own, you'd want to use the [Feed channel](https://ifttt.com/feed) with the "New feed item" or "New feed item matches" (simple search) trigger (as your THIS). Then add the [Email channel](https://ifttt.com/email) with the "Send me an email" action (as your THAT).

Comment: I used the recipe you mentioned and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another option is https://www.feedmyinbox.com/. Free for 2 feeds, if you want more you have to pay

Answer (score 2):

If the source uses [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/) to manage their feed(s) you can easily sign up to receive the feed via email. (Just click the link "Get {feed name} delivered by email" when you click the Feedburner link.

Alternatively, you can set up your own Feedburner account and pull in the site's RSS feed and subscribe by email that way. If they make changes to the feed, though, you have no control.